# Xamarin Android manual sign apk

Tags: apk, jar-signing, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to sign manually my apk, but on terminal I receive this error:
zipalign: command not found.

I've verified and the zipalign file is correctly inside the /Users/myname/android-sdks/tools/

Is all right because I've installed Android build tools (last version) from the "SDK Manager".

Any idea?!?

Seems a path problem (in Windows usually is it!)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to copy the zipalign file from /Users/myname/android-sdks/tools/ folder to /Users/giulianocandreva/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/

Then open the SDK Command Prompt from Xamarin:
[image]

And now works well.